# Pyinstaller Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ctypes'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, ctypes

I am trying to make my Python program executable using Pyinstaller. However, I am getting error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ctypes'. In my code, I import ctypes as "from ctypes import *".

After some digging, I found this website with a "potential" solution but it is not very clear. I have no idea what I should be doing next. If anyone understands what the error is or how to fix it, please help. Thanks a lot!

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/feature-notes.html

Comment: `ctypes` is an included module in the standard Python installation.  Your link refers to the DLLs loaded by `ctypes`, not `ctypes` itself.  You'll have to make a [mcve] for us to reproduce the failure.

Comment: FYI, I created a simple 1-function DLL, called it with `ctypes` in a script, and ran `pyinstaller -F test.py` to create a one-file .exe.  It worked so you'll have to be more specific about recreating the issue.

Comment: I am sorry if the post was not clear enough. The code is not written just by me, but also others so I do not really want to show the code here. However, we did import ctypes to use ctypes.windll.kernel32(), and function such as c_ulong, c_char_p, etc. We use them in one of the class to check for Window Event objects.

Comment: You don't need to post sensitive code.  Any code that uses `ctypes` might reproduce the error.  If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't describe a fix.  `ctypes` comes with Python, so it shouldn't be missing.  At the very least post the build output of PyInstaller that shows the error and the command line used to build.

Comment: I started by running "pyinstaller --onedir J1939App.pyw" in the cmd. However, the .pyw file requires some other modules from its parent directory as well, so I edited the J1939App.spec file by adding into "a.data" fields in tuple format. Then I run the command again but using the spec file instead. When I try to run the executed file, this error shows up. 

https://ibb.co/jztTpjv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using cx_freeze. At first I still got the same error, but I fixed it by adding this line.

```
options={'build_exe': {'packages': ['ctypes', 'xml'], 'include_files': includefiles}}
```

The ctypes package has to be added in manually in the setup.py file for cx_freeze. I assume something similar needs to be done with the pyinstaller spec file.